# How to attach InputStream/OutputStream to background RunLoop?

Tags: swift, cocoa, foundation

I've written a quick class for 'piping' the contents of an InputStream to multiple OutputStreams. It starts this by doing:

```
self.from.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
self.to.forEach { to in
    to.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
}
```

This works fine when I'm in the main thread, but if I try to do it on a background thread nothing ever fires. From my research I understand that this is because the RunLoop only automatically runs on the main thread.

It's often a download task, so from my understanding I don't really want that on the main thread. So how can I best have this run on a background queue?

Comment: How are you starting this background thread?  Does it have a run loop?  MCVE!

Comment: Do you *run* the runloop on the background queue? Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819872/how-to-make-nsrunloop-work-inside-a-separate-thread.

Comment: At the moment I don't have a background queue - I'd like to know the best way to create one. I've used DispatchQueue.global() before, but I'm not at all clear on how that maps to a RunLoop, and how I might then go about running that RunLoop.

Comment: @Alastair Do you find solution for this ?